# CSS Media Query and Mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I'm trying to make different dimension of one modal.

If I resize in the Browser the change is what I want.

[image]

But, if I change the Chrome to simulate a mobile environment or if I open the code at my phone it doesn't work.

[image]

I the example I tried to make a mobile first approach. My `dialog-content` is white as default. Then I change to blue if the width is bigger than 750px and to black if is bigger than 1000px. I make other change too but the color is the important one in the examples.

I would like to know why my "default" case is not working for mobile.

The code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-responsiva-9qir0?file=/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding viewport `meta` tag in the `head` of the document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
     <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```